# Run contracts and create traces with Node

Tags: contract-debugging, javascript, javascript-vm

I came across an article:
https://wanderer.github.io/ethereum/nodejs/code/2014/08/12/running-contracts-with-vm/

At the bottom of the page is shown how to write a contract execution route.
But unfortunately it does not work for me, I do not know too much javascript. Can anyone say what I need to improve?

```
var VM = require('ethereumjs-vm')

var vm = new VM()
var code = '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'

vm.runCode({
    code: Buffer.from(code, 'hex'), // code needs to be a Buffer
    gasLimit: Buffer.from('ffffffff', 'hex')
  }, function(err, results){
    console.log('returned: ' + results.return.toString('hex'));
  })

 vm.onStep = function (info, done) {
    //prints the program counter, the current opcode and the amount of gas left 
    console.log('[vm] ' + info.pc + ' Opcode: ' + info.opcode + ' Gas: ' + info.gasLeft.toString());

    //prints out the current stack
    info.stack.forEach(function (item) {
        console.log('[vm]    ' + item.toString('hex'));
    });
    //important! call `done` when your done messing around
    done();
};

vm.onStep()
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Is there an error?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you found that format for `vm.onStep`.

But from [this example](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-vm/blob/master/examples/run-transactions-simple/index.js) it seems like you should try this format:

```
vm.on('step', function (data) {
    console.log('[vm] ' + data.pc + ' Opcode: ' + data.opcode + ' Gas: ' + data.gasLeft.toString());
    data.stack.forEach(function (item) {
        console.log('[vm]    ' + item.toString('hex'));
    });
};
```

You might want to put this before `vm.runCode` like in the example.